# How to sort a laravel Form::Select alphabetically

Tags: php, laravel

I have been asked to make a change on a laravel project here on site. The change is requesting a dropdown box with company names be sorted alphabetically. I have been searching for a while, and either I am not phrasing the question correctly, or I don't understand the answers. I hope that the code snippet below will explain what I am trying to do.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="company" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ Form::select('company', $companies, $company, array( 'autocomplete' => 'off') ); }}

            </div>
        </div>
```

This is from the php blade file setup in laravel. 
I've seen elsewhere that adding the ->name indicator after the $var will do this, however after doing so the page breaks. Is there an obvious answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the level of easy you are looking for but the following will probably work:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="company" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        Company:
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <?php asort($companies); ?>
        {{ Form::select('company', $companies, $company, array( 'autocomplete' => 'off') ); }}    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked well. Let me ask an addition clarification. Is there a way to set a default value, say a certain value, such as a particular company, or an ALL?

Comment: That's supposed to be the purpose of the 3rd parameter (in this case the `$company`) variable. E.g. if you have `$companies = [ "all" => "All companies", "first" => "First company" ]` you can set `$company` to be `all` to have the entry with key `all` selected.